# Cocos2D Asteroids

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, physics, chipmunk

For school I have to make a game for my iPod touch, I chose to do an asteroids game. I have just started with cocos2d but have read the wenderlich blog. I wanted to use chipmunk in my game, i want realisitc motion of the ship. Is there a tutorial on creating the asteroids motion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Simple Way**

Learn a bit about vectors. http://chortle.ccsu.edu/VectorLessons/vectorIndex.html

Movement is usually calculated by adding a vector scaled by a time delta to the current position. (Math talk makes simple things so complicated).

Basically: new_Pos = old_Pos + mov_Vec * time_delta

So by changing the mov_Vec you can increase/decrease speed.

You can also do it on x,y new_x = old_x + mov_x * time_delta

**Using Physics Library**

If you are using a physics library, you can apply force to an object to move it. You can also set the angular velocity if you want it to rotate.

If you were using Box2d you would do something like this:

```
body->ApplyImpulse( b2Vec2(1,1), body->GetWorldCenter() );
```

*There's a difference between applying force and an impulse in box2d*

Some sites to check out

- http://gpwiki.org/
- http://www.gamedev.net/
- http://www.devmaster.net/
- http://box2d.org/

Comment: Applying a force means the force is persistent, like gravity, whereas an impulse is momentary like a punch.

Answer (score 0):

Airship motion in space is pretty easy to simulate... I don't think you need a library for that.
The ship has a velocity vector: depending on your input method, you shall only add a vector to change the speed (or reduce modulo when braking, if braking is allowed).
Just limit the max modulo of the ship, and you're done.

Sorry if this isn't really a reply to your answer.
HIH